# Prop in interpolation (tailwind, react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I've problem with pass some colors as prop to component in this the prop is interpolated to className.

What's interesting that way works for color like green, orange, but no for e.g. violet, blue, cyan

There's component:

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  title: any;
  desc: any;
  color: any;
  icon: any;
  width: any;
};

function CardWordpress({ title, desc, color, icon, width }: Props) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`bg-white dark:bg-black/80 p-8 w-[100%] lg:w-${width} rounded-2xl`}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div
          className={`bg-${color}-200 dark:bg-${color}-700 flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-[75px] h-[75px]`}
        >
          {icon}
        </div>
        <h3 className="fo-medium">{title}</h3>
        <p className="card text-gray-500">{desc}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardWordpress;
```

Here usage

```
<CardWordpress
                title="Title"
                desc="Description"
                color="violet"
                icon={
                  <BsShopWindow
                    size={40}
                    className="text-violet-500 dark:text-violet-300"
                  />
                }
                width="[30%]"
              />
```

Julian

Please for hints regarding my issue but also for good programming practices, I'm beginner and I would like to avoid bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> Don't construct class names dynamically
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```

The reason it works for some colors like you say is because the complete, unbroken strings of those classes (`bg-green-200`, `bg-orange-200`, etc.) are found elsewhere in your project and not from this code. Instead, consider using some kind of variation mapping. For the `lg:w-*`, consider passing the prop `width` value as a CSS variable and using that CSS variable value in an arbitrary value class.

```
function CardWordpress({ title, desc, color, icon, width }: Props) {
  const colors = {
    green: 'bg-green-200 dark:bg-green-700',
    red: 'bg-red-200 dark:bg-red-700',
    // etc.
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`bg-white dark:bg-black/80 p-8 w-[100%] lg:w-[--width] rounded-2xl`}
      style={{ '--width': width }}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div
          className={`${colors[color]} flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-[75px] h-[75px]`}
        >
          {icon}
        </div>
        <h3 className="fo-medium">{title}</h3>
        <p className="card text-gray-500">{desc}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've got error with these lines:

```style={{ '--width': width }}```
ts(2322)

```className={`${colors[color]} flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-[75px] h-[75px]`}```
ts(7053)

Could you explain me what's wrong?

Comment: What's the error? I expect you'd need to adapt the code for Typescript.

Comment: Type error: Type '{ "--width": any; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"--width"' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.

it's regarding "width"

Okay, I got it, but how to do that? Could you support me?